# Postfix + Dovecot taking too long to send emails

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot, ruby-on-rails

I'm getting 504 errors when trying to send emails on my Rails 4.2 site using dovecot and postfix. I also have an asynchronous email server set up using Redis and Sidekiq, when I send asynchronous emails they take 5 to 30 minutes to send.

My mail server is running on the same box as my site, but the interesting thing is that when I run my development server on my home computer, it connects to my site's mail server and sends mail quickly and without issue.

I have tried looking through my `mail.log` as well as every other log in my `/var/log` directory but I don't see anything during the period while I'm waiting for mail to be sent but a few spam attacks (I'm running SpamAssassin to shut them down).

My rails server log is also not showing anything useful, t just logs that the email was rendered (not sent) and then restarts the server after a minute.

On both my development and prod servers I'm using the following to connect:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => 'mail.mysite.com',
    :domain => 'mysite.com',
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :openssl_verify_mode  => 'none',
    :user_name => 'myuser@mysite.com',
    :password => 'test'
}
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Here is the result from `dovecot -n`:

```
# 2.2.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 4.2.0-23-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
auth_mechanisms = plain login
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_privileged_group = mail
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date ihave
namespace inbox {
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}
protocols = imap pop3 sieve
service auth-worker {
  user = vmail
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 0
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!LOW:!SSLv2:ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
ssl_key = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
protocol pop3 {
  mail_max_userip_connections = 10
  pop3_client_workarounds = outlook-no-nuls oe-ns-eoh
}
protocol imap {
  imap_client_workarounds = delay-newmail
  mail_max_userip_connections = 10
}
protocol lda {
  deliver_log_format = msgid=%m: %$
  mail_plugins = sieve
  postmaster_address = postmaster
  quota_full_tempfail = yes
  rejection_reason = Your message to <%t> was automatically rejected:%n%r
}
```

And `postconf -n`:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf -m "${EXTENSION}"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = mysite.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

Comment: Where are the 504 errors you are referring to? Have you tried a direct telnet to port 25 to test?

Comment: 504 is a timeout error, my guess is that it is caused by the email taking to long to process.

Comment: @RyanBabchishin what kind of test can I run in telnet?

Comment: what program is timing out? Where are you seeing that? In your question you say there's nothing in the logs.

Comment: `telnet mail.example.com 25` and enter manual SMTP commands to send a message.

Comment: I'm seeing the 504 in my browser, once the rails server gives up and restarts. I'll try the telnet command, but I probably need to try port 587 right?

Comment: Yes, if that's where your postfix is listening

Comment: I went through the steps here: http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/8/6/postfix-using-telnet-to-test-postfix

On both port 25 and 587 (secure and where I'm trying to send email from), everything looks ok although 587 states "Must issue a STARTTLS command first"

Answer (score 0):

My issue turned out to be a two-fold problem:

1. **I needed to add `permit_mynetworks` to `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`**

   My `postfix/main.cf` required that I have

   ```
   mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
   smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks
   ```

2. **Since I have two Sidekiq servers running, I needed to use separate queues**

   I am running a staging and production server on the same machine, it turned out that emails were often ending up in the wrong queue, which was causing exceptions, and the emails were subsequently re-queued and further delayed. To get around this I needed to separate the queues by amending my `config/sidekiq.yml` to include:

   ```
   :queues:
     - staging
   ```

   and send email in the following manner:

   ```
   UserMailer.delay(queue: Rails.env).my_email(args)
   ```

After doing this I made sure to clear out my Redis and Sidekiq queues since some bad emails were still clogging up the system and now emails, even with the delay, send very quickly.

- [Clear your Redis queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683222)
- [Clear your Sidekiq queue](http://hacknplay.com/cli/clear-sidekiq-retries-queue/)